# Why does included libary project changes the title of my Android App?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, title, qr-code

I've implemented the ZXing QR code reader in my Android Application (inside the App, so no second App gets installed).
I've included the ZXing Project an a Libary.
Everything works fine, but the included Libary project somehow overwrites the App Title of my App.
Do I have to delete the String values from the Libary project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to delete the String values from the Libary project?

Yes.

If an apk libraries resources have the same names as your applications resources they will override your applications resource values.

A good method to use for apk libraries is to prepend the resource names with the libraries package name.

e.g. in your case, in the zxing libs strings.xml

```
<string name="app_name">Barcode Scanner</string>
```

Would become something like:

```
<string name="com_google_zxing_client_android_app_name">Barcode Scanner</string>
```